# Remove from RecyclerView specif item Kotlin/Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i don't know how to remove specific item in firestore database. I already have position of this item but don't have an id of document.

variable "product" is a position of this product in firestore database.

```
fun deleteItem(product: Int) {
    db.collection("products").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->

        Log.v(TAG, "Remove fun 0 $product");
        Log.v(TAG, "Remove fun 1" + snapshot.toString());
        Log.v(TAG, "Remove fun 2" + e.toString());

        db.collection("products").document().delete()
        
    }
}
```

result of my test from logcat:

```
2023-02-25 12:25:04.413 15627-15627/com.example.foodorder V/ContentValues: Remove fun 0 1
2023-02-25 12:25:04.413 15627-15627/com.example.foodorder V/ContentValues: Remove fun 1com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot@cf2d6530
2023-02-25 12:25:04.413 15627-15627/com.example.foodorder V/ContentValues: Remove fun 2null
```

my adapter file https://pastebin.com/035iqP5G

Comment: Could you also show us your Product class?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it

```
private fun deleteItem(productName: String) {

    val collectionRef = db.collection("products")
    val query = collectionRef.whereEqualTo("name", productName)

    query.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
        for (document in documents) {
            val documentId = document.id
            db.collection("products").document(documentId).delete()
            Log.d(TAG,"Succes")
            notifyDataSetChanged()
            (context as Activity).recreate()
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed: ", exception)
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).